# AppwriteException: User (role: guest) missing scope (account), not able to get account after creating a session

Tags: node.js, authentication, localhost, appwrite

Throwing error on line account.get()
Stuck on this from past 3 days can anyone help me please

Register account controller code :

```
const User = require('../model/User');
const { Client, Account } = require('appwrite');

exports.register = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { name, email, password } = req.body;

        // Validate data if exist
        if (!(name && email && password)) {
            return res.status(401).json({
                success: false,
                message: "All fields are required"
            })
        }

        // Check user already exist or not
        const doesExist = await User.findOne({ email })
        if (doesExist) {
            return res.status(401).json({
                success: false,
                message: "User already exists"
            })
        }

        //check if email is in correct format
        if (!(validateEmail(email))) {
            return res.status(401).json({
                success: false,
                message: "Invalid Email"
            })
        }

        // Save to DB
        const user = await User.create({
            name,
            email,
        })

        user.password = undefined

        const client = new Client()
            .setEndpoint('http://localhost/v1')
            .setProject(`${process.env.APPWRITE_PROJECT_ID}`);
        ;

        const account = new Account(client);

        await account.create(
            user._id.toString(),
            email,
            password,
            name
        );

        await account.get()

        return res.status(200).json({
            success: true,
            user,
        })

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(`Error :: register route :: ${error}`);
        return res.status(500).json({
            success: false,
            message: error.message
        })
    }
}

function validateEmail(email) {
    var re = /\S+@\S+\.\S+/;
    return re.test(email);
}
```

Login account controller code :

```
const User = require('../model/User');
const { Client, Account } = require('appwrite');

exports.login = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { email, password } = req.body;

        // Validate data
        if (!(email && password)) {
            res.status(401).send('All fields are required')
        }

        // check if user exist
        const user = await User.findOne({ email })

        // if user does not exist
        if (!user) {
            return res.status(401).json({
                success: false,
                message: "User does not exist"
            })
        }

        const client = new Client()
            .setEndpoint('http://localhost/v1')
            .setProject(`${process.env.APPWRITE_PROJECT_ID}`);
        ;

        const account = new Account(client);


        await account.createEmailSession(
            email,
            password,
        );

        await account.get()


        return res.status(200).json({
            success: true,
            user,
        })


    } catch (error) {
        console.log(`Error :: login route :: ${error}`);
        return res.status(500).json({
            success: false,
            message: error.message
        })
    }
}
```

I tried reading Appwrite docs to change permission for guest role, but didn't find anything for account.get(). It was for databases and files. And read some issues regarding this that i should use appwrite locally but even after install it locally, problem stays the same.

Comment: I have'nt use Appwrite, but I guess you must have a session to use ```account.get``` method. And you are creating only the account but not the session. I could try that first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the session on the client-side. If you attempt to create a session server-side, it will result in a cookies header being returned, which the server will ignore and the session will be created, but the session information will not be stored anywhere.

Also, if I may ask, why do you need a server in the middle of your Client and backend?

Appwrite does a lot of heavy lifting for you as a Backend as a Service and hence you don't need to implement things yourself. If you point me to your use-case, maybe I can help you eliminate manual implementations.

Comment: Yes, you are exactly right. Session weren't storing from backend, so i implemented it in client side. Actually i was making changes in my backend which was based on JWT token based approach to Appwrite. But later i realized how i should implement appwrite.                                                                                                                                          Thank you 

Comment: Hy @Joe, I'm running appwrite with nuxt so when I try to get the session on the initializer plugin, it's only settle on the client side. (I see everything right on the browser and an error on node console), which gives me an error of hydration since I'm using this logic to change my view. How can I make a proper call on the backend as well?